# Parse XML in PHP to variables

Tags: php, xml

I have made a PHP script that need to receive the following XML:

```
<contact_email>people@example.com</contact_email>
<contact_password>hash_in_sha256</contact_password>
```

I usually do stuff with JSON, but in this project I need to use XML. So, to parse the JSON objects in PHP I use the following code with the following JSON:

```
{
    "contact_email":"people@example.com",
    "contact_password":"hash_in_sha256"
}
```

The script:

```
$jsonBody = file_get_contents("php://input");
$jsonBody = json_decode($jsonBody);

$contact_email = $jsonBody->contact_email;
$contact_password = $jsonBody->contact_password;
```

But what should I do to have "people@example.com" and "hash_in_sha256" from the XML as a variable in PHP?

Comment: try `simplexml_load_string` .

Comment: Sahil Gulati: Doesn't works

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parsing XML with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5048858/parsing-xml-with-php)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you parse and process HTML/XML in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like Sahil Gulati said, use `simplexml_load_string`, just make sure you have valid xml, there should only be one top node, eg:

```
$input = "<contact><contact_email>people@example.com</contact_email><contact_password>hash_in_sha256</contact_password></contact>";

$xml = simplexml_load_string($input);

echo $xml->contact_email;
echo $xml->contact_password;
```